# What happens when table references are wrapped in parenthesis (in front of a JOIN)?

Tags: mysql, sql

The JOIN syntax operates of a single table reference (from the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) :

```
table_reference JOIN table_factor ON condition
```

What happens behind the scenes if I put multiple table references inside parenthesis and use that as the 'table_reference'?

```
(t1, t2, t3) JOIN (SELECT X FROM ... ) t4 ON (t4.X = t1.Y)
```

Without parenthesis, I get an error: 'Unknown column 't1.Y' in 'on clause'.  This makes sense as it's only attempting to join with t3.  However, with parenthesis it works.

Comment: Funny that it's all explained in the manual page you gave a link to, isn't it? Apart from that, in my years of working with sql I've never come across a situation where there's a need to have a cartesian product of tables. Never ever. So, why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this expression:

```
from t1,
     t2,
     t3 join
     (select x. . . ) t4
     on t4.X = t1.Y
```

Then this is interpreted as:

```
from t1,
     t2,
     (t3 join
      (select x. . . ) t4
      on t4.X = t1.Y
     )
```

In other words, the `join` is done before the comma, because the `join` has higher precedence than `,` (the same reason you get 11 rather than 30 if you do 10*2 + 1).  If you replaced the `,` with the seemingly equivalent `cross join`, then the query would work:

```
from t1 cross join
     t2 cross join
     t3 join
     (select x. . . ) t4
     on t4.X = t1.Y
```

This is because precedence rules for `cross join` are different than for `,`.

The parentheses tell the compiler the order of "interpretation" for the joins.  So, when you do:

```
from (t1, t2, t3) join
     (select X from ... ) t4 on (t4.X = t1.Y)
```

The columns from `t1` are available.

The moral of the story:  Don't use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit joins, even for `cross join`.

Comment: This is very clear (more so than the documentation).  Thanks!